# How to create and maintain multiple instances of an NSManagedObject before saving in Core Data / Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

(Not sure that i've worded my question particularly well, anyway....)

I have a 'Match' Entity where the user can choose which players (from a linked 'Player' entity) are playing in the match and which 'Game' (from a linked 'Game' entity) they are playing. This all works fine and the data is successfully stored in coredata.

I then have a 'MatchGame' entity that is linked to the 'Match' entity via a many-to-one relationship (i.e. one match can contain many games). The attributes of my MatchGame entity are: score[Int16]; result[string]; match[via relationship to match entity]; player[via a new relationship with the 'Player' entity].

In my MatchGameScoring viewController I need an instance of the MatchGame entity to be initialised for **each** player in the match so that this will record the player, their score in the game and their game result (i.e. if they won, lost or drew).

How best can I go about setting this up for each of the players contained in the Match Entity's NSSet? i.e. How do I create and maintain 2 or more concurrent instances of an item? Is there a way to create a loop so that for each player listed in my Match entity a newMatchGamePlayer1, newMatchGamePlayer2 etc is generated that I can then use to track the scores for each player before saving the data.